# Android custom portrait camera and images orientation

Tags: android, camera, rotation

I am writing a custom portrait camera and I am having some issues with images orientation.
In details, I need always the camera to be in portrait orientation and it happens using the manifest configuration:

android:screenOrientation="portrait"

and I set in application:

```
customCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

which works, because when I rotate the device (90,180,270 degrees) I can see (from camera preview) the right image.

I don't care when the device orientation is locked (disabled), but when it's enabled, it seems that I don't get any orientation change. I always get 0 degrees using the code:

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

Technically, I need to write to the taken picture (using exif data) 0,1,3,6 or 8 value.
So, the steps are:
1) set the right orientation on custom portrait camera - DONE!
2) Preview the right picture - DONE!
3) If the device orientation in enabled, get the current rotation (0.90,180,270 degrees)
4) Write the taken picture with the right orientation exif tag.

I am using Samsung Galaxy I for the development.

The question is: How can i get the device orientation when the application shows always a custom portrait camera, which should never be rotated, but the device orientation is enabled?

Thank you,
Nikolaos

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html)

```
OrientationEventListener mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(
            this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        }

    };
```